# Determining orders of elements in quotient ring with SAGE

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, sagemath

I wish to determine whether certain elements of the quotient ring $Q:=\mathbb{F}_{2}[x]/\langle (x^{5}-1)^2\rangle$ are units and, in the case that they are indeed units, I would also like to compute their multiplicative orders. How can one go about doing this?

In case you consider that my previous questions is a wee bit too broad, I have a related question which is more specific: if $p(x) \in \mathbb{F}_{2}[x]$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, how does one even determine a representative of the class (in the ring $Q$) to which $(p(x))^{k}$ belongs? The naïve approach does not seem to work here: in my viewpoint, the code

> F = GF(2)
>
> R. = PolynomialRing(F)
>
> S. = R.quo((x^5-1)^2)
>
> b=x^5-1
>
> b^2

**SHOULD** output [0] because the image of $(x^{5}-1)^2$ under the natural projection $\mathbb{F}_{2}[x] \to Q$ is exactly equal to the zero element of the quotient ring $Q$, but it does not yield that (it outputs the polynomial $x^{10}+1$ instead, duh!). Do you know how it is that I am supposed to modify it in order to get the actual class in $Q$ to which $(x^{5}-1)^{2}$ belongs?

Thanks in advance for your insightful replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also in [magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)

```
   F := GF(2);
   R<x> := PolynomialRing(F);
   I := ideal<R|(x^5-1)^2>;
   S<y> := quo<R|I>;

   for a in [0..1] do
    for b in [0..1] do
      c := a+b*y;
      if IsUnit(c) then
        [c,c^(-1)];
      end if;
     end for;
   end for;
```

Comment: Is this a code in magma?

Comment: @Jamai-Con Sure. In sage the syntax is `R.<x>` instead of `R<x>`

Comment: It only determines which of the elements of $\{[0],[y],[1],[1+y]\}$ are units, right? Is there a quick way to determine the multiplicative orders of a given unit with MAGMA?

Comment: @Jamai-Con I don't know why I didn't find it. But you can compute the order of $S^\times$ by factoring the polynomial

Comment: it can also be computed by means of a while loop, right?

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help, reuns! I think I have managed to implement  a loop to determine the orders in question. For instance, the order of $1+y^{4}+y^{8}$ can be obtained thus: F := GF(2); R<x> := PolynomialRing(F); I := ideal<R|(x^5-1)^2>; S<y> := quo<R|I>; c:=1+y^4+y^8; e:=1; k:=1; while c^k ne 1 do k:=k+1; e:=e+1; end while; e